# Server error в Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Создаю веб-приложение, использую socket.io. Возникла ошибка Server error при подключении к серверу. Выяснили, что ошибка в бэкенде. Что может быть написано неверно здесь?
Код:

```
// Константы для сервера
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const fs = require("fs");
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('путь').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('путь').toString();


const http = require('https').Server({key:privateKey,cert:certificate}, app);



const io = require('socket.io')(http);


// Необходимые переменные
const port = 9998;
const debug = true;
var connectedArray = new Array()
const delay = 60 * 1000


// Подключение к бд
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const db = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'пользователь',
    password: 'пароль',
    database: 'бд',
});

// Непосредственно само принятие запросов через socket.io
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    
    socket.on('register', msg => {
        console.log("User registered")
        connectedArray.push({
            connectmessage: msg,
            socket: socket,
        })
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        if (debug) console.log('User disconnected')
    })

})
        
setInterval(() => {
    let count = 0
    for (let arr of connectedArray) {
        if (arr.socket.disconnected) {
            connectedArray = connectedArray.slice(count, 1)
        }
        count++
    }
}, 1000)         


app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'static')))
            
// Сервер слушает
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('./index.html')
})
            
http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started listening on port ${port}...`)
})
```

Проблема стала возникать после привязки домена, даже при обращении по ip

Comment: можно текст ошибки в студию? :)

Comment: ```
Error: server error
    at a.value (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6)
    at s.T.emit (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6)
    at s.value (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6)
    at socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at s.value (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6)
    at o.T.emit (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6)
    at o.value (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6)
    at o.value (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.n.onreadystatechange (socket.io.min.js:sourcemap:6)```

Comment: ну, по минифицированной версии мало что понятно, но можно пальцем в небо - покажите урл подключения к вебсокету

Comment: @StrangerintheQ https://sourceeyes.querlit.com:9998

Comment: @StrangerintheQ проблема возникла после привязки домена, и есть несколько сайтов на разных виртуальных хостах, может проблема быть в этом?